# Есть ли способ сохранить id который приходит в ссылку /serve/:id?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Отправляю id нажатием на кнопку

```
<Button  variant="outline-success" onClick={() => 
{   
window.location.href='edit';
this.props.getServThunk(m._id);
}} 
className="right">Edit</Button>
```

Айди поподает сюда

```
const SET_SERV = 'SET_SERV';

let initialState = { 
    serve:[]
};
switch(action.type) {
    case SET_SERV:
        return {...state, serve: [...state.serve, ...action.serve]}

    default:
        return state;

}
export const setServ = (serve) => ({type:SET_SERV, serve});
export const getServThunk = (ServID) => {
    return (dispatch) => {
    getServis(ServID).then(data => 
        { 
            dispatch(setServ(data));
        }
    );
    }
}
```

Потом попадает сюда

```
export const getServis = (ServID) => {
    return baseRout.get(`serve/${ServID}`).then(response => {return response.data})
}
```

и отсюда уже к серверу

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const DB = require('../DB');
const serve = require("../schemas/servers");


router.get('/serve/:id', (req, res) => {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'origin, content-type, accept');
    console.log(req.params.id);
    serve.find({_id : req.params.id}, (err, serve) => {
        console.log(req.params.id);
        
        if(err)
        { 
            throw err;
        }
        else
        {
            return res.send(serve)
        }

       })

  });

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, добавляйте код текстом, а не изображением, чтобы отвечающим было легче копировать и тестировать фрагменты.

Comment: что такое "начинаю использовать"? где в этом коде "использовать"? `console.log(serverId)` - понятно, а где "undefinde"?

Comment: Использую здесь и тут же получаю undefinde
serve.findOne({_id: serverId }, (err, serve) => {

Comment: ну, тогда тут для отвечающих просто гадание. может нет такой записи в коллекции serve. может вместо findOne стоит использовать findById. может в полнолуние появится.

Comment: в коллекции есть , а причём тут findById если undefinde кидает на serverId который приходит с компонента когда я на кнопку жму, проблема в том что он приходит и проподает при обновлении другого компонента где я выполняю выборку из бд.

Comment: как можно сохранить значение в serverId до прихода нового?

Comment: вы в двух местах пишете `//здесь его уже нет пишет undefinde`, но этого дебага нет в коде. что-то я не понимаю

Comment: Довольно много здесь неизвестных. Попробуйте написать с помощью async await. Поставить try catch. Продебажить это всё

Comment: вторая часть кода это выборка из бд из первого , там и выскакивает undefinde возможно из-за того что значение приходит по нажатию кнопки , а выборка происходит после монтирования страницы, можно ли как то сделать что бы выборка сработала сразу после того как в ссылку придёт значение id

Comment: а если вот так? https://pastebin.com/28DZU6fT

Comment: асинхронно пробовал но немного не так , утром попробую как у вас отпишу

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В роуте переделал обработчик запроса:

```
router.get('/serve/:id', async (req, res) => {
  const items = await serve.find({ _id: req.params.id });
 
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'origin, content-type, accept');
  res.send(items);
});
```

Comment: а можно ли как-то задержать эти данные до прихода новых?